# VBA - Find max percent change based on values in two different sheets in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I've been staring at this for so long and I honestly have no clue how to do it. Assume I have Sheet1 which has Employee ID in column A and Salary in column B for January 2016, and Employee ID and Salary in column A and B for December 2016 on Sheet2. How would I go about writing a for loop that finds the max percent difference in salaries based on employer ID? I would need to use some form of Vlookup since they don't match exactly.

Currently, this is what I have:

```
Sub Max_Percent_Change()
Dim Salary

For Each Cell In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A1000")
        Salary = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cell, _
                Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:B1000"), 2, False)
```

Answer (score 0):

If data is setup as shown in the images, please give this a try...

Change the sheet names if required in the code.

```
Sub FindSalaryPercentageChange()
Dim wsJan As Worksheet, wsDec As Worksheet
Dim x, y, z()
Dim i As Long
Dim janSalary As Double, decSalary As Double
Dim pChng As Double
Dim r
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wsJan = Sheets("January16")
Set wsDec = Sheets("December16")
x = wsJan.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
y = wsDec.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
ReDim z(1 To UBound(x, 1) - 1)
wsDec.Columns("C").Clear
For i = 2 To UBound(y, 1)
    r = Application.Match(y(i, 1), Application.Index(x, , 1), 0)
    If Not IsError(r) Then
        janSalary = x(r, 2)
        decSalary = y(i, 2)
        pChng = (decSalary - janSalary) / janSalary
        z(i - 1) = pChng
    End If
Next i
wsDec.Range("C1").Value = "%Change"
wsDec.Range("C2").Resize(UBound(z)).Value = Application.Transpose(z)
wsDec.Columns(3).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**January16 Data:**

[image]

**December16 Data:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! But is there a way to do it so that it doesn't modify the current spreadsheet? Aka so that all the calculations are done in VBA itself?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean when you say all the calculations are done in VBA itself? The variable Array z holds all the percentage change between Jan and Dec salaries, you can do whatever you wish to do with this Array, whether write back it on to the sheet or do something with it in the code.